# dataset возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript

У меня в браузерах не работает dataset. Что в firefox, что в хроме. Код беру прям из учебных примеров. Вот код:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('widget');
var widgetName = div.dataset.widgetName;
 alert( widgetName );
```

```html
<div id="widget" data‐widget‐name="menu">Выберите жанр</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас в названии атрибута `data-widget-name` вместо дефиса используется юникодный символ HYPHEN (`e2 80 90`). Это можно увидеть, если скопировать ваш HTML код в какой-нибудь HEX-редактор. Сотрите то, что маскируется под дефис, и введите руками с клавиатуры:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('widget');
var widgetName = div.dataset.widgetName;
 alert( widgetName );
```

```html
<div id="widget" data-widget-name="menu">Выберите жанр</div>
```

Полагаю, что HYPHEN там взялся при копировании кода в какой-нибудь Google Docs или другой умный текстовые редактор.